# Prevent int looping round in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column, labelled int(11) not null unsigned.

It has a value, say 10.

When I run a query which -11 from this, it loops around to 4294967295.

What I actually want is for it to just go to zero.

I am using php to run the query, so if that can be used to find a solution, great!

What do I need to change or do to do this?

Comment: Solution used: Changed to unsigned and hope it will not break anything in future.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SET sql_mode='NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
```

See this manual page for more information:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

Comment: But then how do I minus without unsigned subtraction to equal 0?